# WooCommerce Product Reviews Not Showing Up in Divi theme

Tags: woocommerce, product, review, woocommerce-product-bundles

I've done the obvious, and enabled product reviews on WooCommerce Settings and for individual products, and I'm finding that even when I can see "product reviews" and "stars" on the visual editor backend using the Divi theme...when I (or a friend) navigates to it from an incognito browser, it isn't visible. They are variable pricing products because I try to offer sliding scale for folks.

I've updated WooCommerce and Divi and still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvBob.jpg)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9BGq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmnxb.jpg)

Updated all plugins, themes, enabled product reviews, am not requiring "verified buyers" or being logged in, and can see them on the visual editor backend.

Comment: This is specific to Divi theme, you need to search and ask in Divi theme support pages…

Comment: By any chance reviews are enabled only for customers who purchased the item ?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - I'll pop over there as we..

Comment: @Snuffy - yep, reviews are enabled for anyone!